# Clear column and row

Tags: excel, vba, row

Need vba code to Clear column from A to J and row from 21 to 200. Below code is clearing the column till end, need to delete till column J

```
Function ClearSummary()


Const TestName_Col = "B"   
Const FirstRow_Num = "21"   

    MaxRowNumber = Range(TestName_Col & "200").End(xlUp).Row

    If (MaxRowNumber > FirstRow_Num) Then
        'select all rows in range & clear
        CellReference = FirstRow_Num & ":" & MaxRowNumber
        Rows(CellReference).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick!

```
Range("A21:J200").Clear
```

Thumbs up to Chris for teaching me a new method!

Comment: No need for `Select` , just do it in one step `Range("A21:J200").Clear`

Comment: Just FYI to all, this will clear any saved formulas and not just the current values.

Answer (score 1):

A spin off of **t.thielemans** answer for those who do not want to lose things such as formatting or data validation

`Range("A21:J200").ClearContents`

This will ensure that you keep everything except the current value of the cells selected.